# bipartite network graph can have block diagonal matrix?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

This is a bipartite network. 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wntHM.png)

If you create it's adjacency matrix you see that it's diagonal contains zero elements, and two blocks.

is it a block-diagonal matrix? I can see two blocks, but I think that the graph is one connected component and not two (two blocks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For block-diagonal form, the blocks must be along the main diagonal.  In general, the adjacency matrix of a graph is block-diagonal with one block per connected component. For your example, the matrix is block-diagonal with one block but not with two blocks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It help me to understand better. So because this is one connected component, all the adjacency matrix is block diagonal (it's one block)?

Comment: Yes, any matrix is trivially block-diagonal with one block.